# PhpStorm include file outside project from remote host

Tags: php, ssh, phpstorm

I have create a project from existing files over SSH.
PhpStrom copied this project to a local folder on my computer.
When i used the same construction

```
requre '/var/www/libs/log.php';
```

i've got notice from IDE like this: Include expression is not resolved

Project are available on remote server by this path: /var/www/project

How i can resolve this notice?

Comment: require '/var/www/libs/log.php';

Comment: IDE cannot do that -- you have to have local copies of those files. If problem is about warning -- then your either suppress it for this particular line .. or disable whole inspection altogether. For that -- Alt+Enter when having caret on problematic place, choose entry and see submenu (arrow right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do this on Ubuntu Linux, i test it and it works. Here is how to do this. 
1. Open nautilus and connect to your host over sftp (also you can use other file managers)
2. Navigate to folder `/run/user/xxx/gvfs/` where xxx is user uid. Possible you path will be `run/user/1000/gvfs/`
3. Open PhpStorm and add external library pointed to you folder.

The main feature is to mount your remote host folder with local folder.
important: don`t include huge external folders from your host to phpstorm.
Btw it is better to keep all your files locally.

[image: phpstorm external library configure dialog]
[image: phpstorm external library in project index]